# zoo::rollapply does not give the entire run of rolling correlation

Tags: r, dplyr, correlation, zoo, rolling-computation

I was trying to do some manual labour to calculate my own rolling beta for some stock log returns and bumped into this peculiar issue.
To actually reproduce this issue I have paste my full dataset(`csv` file) [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zyju5ab8/).

This dataset has a date column but when I was doing my calculate I have excluded it. Below snippet shall create identical dataset to what I have experimented with.

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

test <- read_csv(YOUR_PATH_TO_MY_DATASET) %>%
        select(-date) %>%
        as.data.table
```

I then ran a rolling apply on the typical `stats::cor` function.

```
library(zoo)

roll.cor <- rollapplyr(test, 
                      width=50, 
                      function(x) cor(x,
                                      method="spearman"),
                      by.column=F)
```

The length of my input column is 1724 (we will refer back to this number shortly.)

Now here's the interesting bit.
I found that the `rollingapply` only went as far as filling up the length of the input matrix (excluding the first `width` number of `obs`), at least in case of `stats::cor` (and `corrr::correlate`).

Here's what I mean: In my example, my window size is 50, therefore the first correlation calculation would take the first 50 `obs` of the matrix. e.g. `test$A[1:50]` vs `test$B[1:50]` and so on. The second calculation would then roll forward by one `ob` and becomes `test$A[2:51]` vs `test$B[2:51]` then we have `test$A[3:52]` vs `test$B[3:52]`, `test$A[4:53]` vs `test$B[4:53]` and so forth. we can easily prove this by:

```
# following results match up with the result we get from rollapply.

cor(testA$[1:50], test$B[1:50], method="spearman")
# 0.6520358
cor(testA$[2:51], test$B[2:51], method="spearman")
# 0.662828385
cor(testA$[3:52], test$B[3:52], method="spearman")
# 0.655938477
```

As the `stats::cor` function returns a correlation matrix of as many rows as the number of variables, every run of `stats:cor` would give me 5 rows in my case. `rollapply` stopped at 335th runs of `stats:cor` simply because `335 * 5 = 1675 (1724 - 49 = 1675)`. If we take out the first 50 `obs` (first `ob` inclusive), we end up with 1675 `obs` and `rollapply` decided to stop once we reached this length. We witness this by,

```
tail(roll.cor, n=5)
cor(test$A[335:384), test$B[335:384], method="spearman")
# 0.6806554
```

Therefore essentially `rollapply` stopped at the 335th of `obs` and the rest of the `obs` was just discarded (at least seems to be the case).

I was nonetheless expecting this rolling mechanism would carry on until we've reached the last 50 `obs`, i.e. `test$A[1675:1724]` vs `test$B[1675:1724]`; by this we'd obtain `1675 * 5 = 8375` number of rows (recall that every run of `stats::cor` gives 5 rows).

Is this supposed to be the way `rolling` works in `R`? or this is something wasn't discovered before?
How can I obtain the "true" full run rolling correlation given my number of `obs` (8375 rows for this example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function should return a vector, not a matrix.  Use the following (or omit the fill argument if you don't want the result to be filled with leading NAs):

```
ccor <- function(x) c(cor(x, method = "spearman"))
rollapplyr(test, 50, ccor, by.column = FALSE, fill = NA)
```

Also

- `require` should only be used within an if (...).  Use `library` in your example.  This will make it easier to debug the existence of missing packages since in that case it will stop at the `library` statement rather than later on when it is harder to determine the cause.
- the right pointing assignment arrows should be left pointing
- in the development version of zoo a matrix or data frame (but not a plain list) output from the function specified in `FUN=` will be unraveled into a vector so this will produce one row for each input row:

  ```
  # install.packages("zoo", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
  rollapplyr(test, 50, cor, method = "spearman", by.column = FALSE, fill = NA)
  ```

Comment: I just edited question details didn’t pay attention to arrows; and thanks for require vs library, I never really dig into the difference between them! It’s too late for me right now I’ll try it out later and get back to you. Thanks !

Comment: it did work as I described above, though not how I wanted it; it spanned across 25 vectors/columns instead of 5 by 5 matrix with no way to identify the actual pair, I can only resort to heuristics to guess what pair that column represents. This'll be a separate issue though.

Comment: Look at `nr <- nrow(test); 
nc <- ncol(test); 
r <- rollapplyr(test, 50, ccor, by.columnn = FALSE, fill = NA); 
a <- array(t(r), c(nc, nc, nr));
matrix(aperm(a, c(1, 3, 2)),, nc)`

Comment: I am frankly speechless; your code definitely shows me the power of base `R`, especially the `aperm`; `tidyverse` is nice to have, but now I am urged to dig deeper into `R` itself. Thanks very much!

Comment: I also tried `corrr::correlate`; it gave me a column based result with nested lists: `ccor2 <- function(x) c(correlate(x, method="spearman", diagonal=1, quiet=T)); r2 <- rollapplyr(test, 50, ccor2, by.column=F)` Then I found this short expression gives me a nice flattened matrix as well: `r2 %>% tidyr::as_tibble() %>% tidyr::unnest()`. `corrr::correlate` however took at least 1 second longer than base `R` implementation you showed me.

Comment: Another approach would be to convert each row to a data frame and then rbind them together: `do.call("rbind", apply(r2[, -1], 1, as.data.frame))`

Comment: Have added some info on the development version of zoo.

Comment: thanks for the added information and sorry for a late reply! I'll try it out over this weekend and revert back. It seems the `dev` version would save a some effort in transforming the data later on.